# python LDAPSocketOpenError: ("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4012)',)",)

Tags: python, ldap

I am hitting LDAP without SSL and everything works fine.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
server = Server(host='prod.prod.com', port=636, use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user='cn=prod,ou=ApplicationUsers,o=prod', password='123456')
conn.start_tls()
conn.bind()
conn.result
print(conn.result)      
{'result': 0, 'description': 'success', 'dn': '', 'message': '', 'referrals': None, 'saslCreds': None, 'type': 'bindResponse'}
```

**When i attempt to use a ssl**

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL,Tls
tls = Tls(local_certificate_file='prodldap.crt', \
    ca_certs_file = 'DigiCertCA.crt', \
    validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
server = Server(host='prod.prod.com', port=636, use_ssl=True, get_info=ALL, tls=tls)
conn = Connection(server, user='cn=prod,ou=ApplicationUsers,o=prod', password='123456', tls=tls)
conn.bind()
conn.result
print(conn)

----> 7 conn.bind()
      8 conn.result
      9 print(conn)

c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py in bind(self, read_server_info, controls)
    559                 self._bind_controls = None
    560                 if self.closed:  # try to open connection if closed
--> 561                     self.open(read_server_info=False)
    562                 if self.authentication == ANONYMOUS:
    563                     if log_enabled(PROTOCOL):

c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py in open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
     54
     55     def open(self, reset_usage=True, read_server_info=True):
---> 56         BaseStrategy.open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
     57         if read_server_info:
     58             try:

c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py in open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
    137                         if log_enabled(ERROR):
    138                             log(ERROR, '<%s> for <%s>', str(exception_history[0][0]) + ' ' + str((exception_history[0][1])), self.connection)
--> 139                         raise exception_history[0][0]
    140                     else:
    141                         if log_enabled(ERROR):
```

And i hit this dreaded error

**LDAPSocketOpenError: ("('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4012)',)",)**

Any ideas what i am doing wrong ?